# Can we customize the android setting options and meta options?

Tags: android, user-interface, settings

I want to create an application but I want to use `Setting Options` in my UI (i.e. every device has a specific user interface but i want to display setting option and meta options in `My User` interface).

I have not done such type of work previously. Does anybody have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Thank you Princepiero for editing you are rock .thank you